# data size on ethereum blockchain

Tags: blockchain, database

can I store a big data size, like 100TB on ethereum blockchain?
and then, is this mean that all clients should download 100TB to get full blockchain data!?

Comment: Welcome. Due to the astronomical cost of making upwards of 30K copies of the 100TB data set, the usual approach is store blobs elsewhere (swarm, ipfs, etc.) and then store record hashes in the blockchain. That way, clients can confirm the fidelity of data loaded from other locations.

Answer (score 2):

That would be extremely expensive.

As the price for 256 bit word is 20,000 gas as stated in [yellow paper](http://yellowpaper.io/) and current gas price is about 20 gwei [eth network stats](https://ethstats.net/) we may calculate that with current ETH price $267:

1KB = 0.0128 ETH     = $3.41

1MB = 13.1 ETH       = $3,497

1GB = 13 421 ETH     = $3,583,407

1TB = 13 743 895 ETH = $3,669,619,965

100TB = 1 374 389 500 ETH = $366,961,996,500

So I'm not sure if you can afford it ;)

It's better to use different distributed storage like [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) or [SWARM](http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/theswarm.eth/).

Answer (score 0):

You would lack the money doing. In theory, yes. But it would cost more than hell.